# Products and Stone-Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$, $Y$ be complete metrizable spaces, $\beta X$, $\beta Y$ be their Stone-Čech compactifications. It is known that $C_b(X) \simeq C(\beta X)$. Is it possible to say something about the relation between $C_b(X \times Y)$ and $C(\beta X \times \beta Y)$?

Comment: For compacts $K$ and $L$ we always have
$$
C(K\times L)\cong_1C(K)\mathop{\otimes}^\varepsilon C(L)
$$
where $\mathop{\otimes}^\varepsilon$ is a completed [injective tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product) product of Banach spaces. For the proof of $(1)$ see Ryan's book Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces (p. 50)

Comment: @Norbert I liked this as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, as you wish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all Tychonoff spaces $X$ and $Y$ we know that $C_b(X \times Y) = C(\beta (X \times Y))$ (isometry as Banach spaces, as well as a ring isomorphism), and $\beta(X \times Y) \cong \beta X \times \beta Y$ iff $X \times Y$ is pseudocompact (see [the original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-03/S0002-9947-1959-0105667-4/S0002-9947-1959-0105667-4.pdf)). The latter happens, in your case, iff $X \times Y$ is compact (pseudocompactness and compactness coincide for metrizable spaces; we only need first countability and normality to see that) iff $X$,$Y$ are compact and everything trivializes, as $\beta X = X$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

For compacts $K$ and $L$ we always have
$$
C(K\times L)\cong_1C(K)\mathop{\otimes}^\varepsilon C(L)
$$
where $\mathop{\otimes}^\varepsilon$ is a completed [injective tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product) product of Banach spaces. For the proof of $(1)$ see Ryan's book Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces (p. 50)