# Dual of injective tensor norm is not projective tensor norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, operator-algebras

Let $A$, $B$ are two Banach space, on the algebraic tensor space $A$ $\odot$ $B$, we can define the projection（maximal） tensor norm $\gamma$ and injective（minimal） tensor norm $\lambda$. For the algebraic tensor space $A*$$\odot$$B*$, we have $\gamma*$=$\lambda$, but $\lambda$* maybe is not $\gamma$.

How to explain that the dual of injective tensor norm maybe is not projective tensor norm? Any simple counterexample?

Comment: What are the cirle with the dot, $*,^*,A\circ B,A*\circ B*,\gamma,\lambda,\gamma *$ and $\lambda^*$?

Comment: You can see wiki here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product

Comment: π and ε are γ and λ, two different symbols, I follow the book Theory of operator algebra I by Takesaki.

Comment: * means dual, both for the space and the tensor product.

Comment: You should make you questions self contained. I still don't know what those symbols mean.

Comment: Yes, it need more background knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We claim that
$$
(c_0\otimes_\varepsilon c_0)^*\neq c_0\otimes_\pi c_0
$$
From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/433513/19538) we know that $c_0\otimes_\varepsilon c_0=c_0$, so
$(c_0\otimes_\varepsilon c_0)^*=c_0^*=\ell_1$
By [result of Kothe](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5597/closed-complemented-subspaces-of-l1x-when-x-is-uncountable) the only infinite dimensional complemented subspce of $l_1$ is $l_1$.

Now, for any Banach spaces $X$, $Y$ the space $X$ is complemened in $X\otimes_\pi Y$ (see ex 2.1 in [Introduction to tensor products of Banach spaces. R. A. Ryan](http://bookfi.org/book/1083697)). Thus $c_0\otimes_\pi c_0 $ have complemented subspace isomorphic to $c_0$.

Since $c_0$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_1$ ($c_0$ [is not a dual space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210043/c-0x-is-not-the-dual-of-a-complete-normed-space) while $\ell_1=c_0^*$), then $(c_0\otimes_\varepsilon c_0)^*$ is not isomorphic to $c_0\otimes_\pi c_0$.

Comment: It is a nice counterexample, thanks. I also want to see some theoretical explaination for this fact.